# Motor power rating and in-rush current

Tags: motor, mains, cables, fuses

I'm looking to replace the cable of a mains (UK 230V nominal +10/-6) appliance, essentially just a motor, rated at 180W.

The existing cable has a 3A fused plug; my options to replace it (restricted since I'm looking for a coiled type) are 1A or 6A. At maximum deviation on the supply, (and assuming the appliance draws a constant power) I calculate 180/224 = 0.8A.

However, I know motors can/do draw a high 'in-rush' current as they start up; I don't know whether this peak or the 'normal operation' is what's specified, nor whether that's standardised at all? (And I'm not really  equipped to measure it.)

Can I replace the 3A fuse & cable with 1A; or should I use the 6A (or look harder for a 3A or closer) variant?

Comment: Use a multimeter. Set it to measure resistance. Measure the motor resistance without it connected or spinning. 230/(measured resistance) ~= inrush current. Have you tried a slow blowing fuse? I would expect around 5-10 A peak inrush.

Comment: @winny Ah, thanks. I haven't tried a slow-blowing fuse, nor anything, just had a quick look for coiled mains flex and could only immediately find 1A or 6A rated cable of the sort I'm after. Could fuse the latter at 3A still of course, just more expensive. Not prohibitively, but by then I was curious..

Comment: Rated current and inrush are two separate problems. You need to rate your cables, fuse and the like for the running current but the inrush is only sets your fuse type/rate/characteristic. Look for “motor start”, “time delay” or “slow blow”.

Comment: Use the 6A cable; just replace the fuse in the plug with a 3A one (and add a prominent "Fused 3A" label on the cable somewhere)

Answer (score 1):

When motors are sold by themselves, not as part of an appliance, the power rating is usually the mechanical output power. In that case, the normal running current could be more than twice the current that you calculated. In a small motor, losses are high and power factor is low, resulting in higher current. That would explain while the original fuse is 3A.

You should find a way to use a fuse that is just like the original fuse.